# Amazon Redshift query editor triggering a query twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert some values in a customer table:

```
INSERT into customer
(c_custkey,c_name,c_address,c_city,c_nation,c_region,c_phone,c_mktsegment)
VALUES (123,'ddf','sfvvc','ccxx','dddd','dddss','sszzs','sssaaaa');
```

I am using the Amazon Redshift Query Editor for this. The query is getting triggered twice and I can see that in STL_QUERY and STV_RECENTS tables.

Can someone help me resolve this and why does it work this way?

Comment: Are you saying that the data is being inserted twice or is it only inserted once?

Comment: It is getting inserted twice for a single insert statement.

Comment: If you ever discovered the reason for this please share.  I have encountered the same situation.